# ModSecurity block specific string in request

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security

I want a ModSecurity rule, which block the access to any url or any Body request Post/Get, if it contains a specific string.

For example i want to block this string : "km0ae9gr6m"

I have this rule in placse but it doesnt seems to be working.

> `SecRule ARGS "km0ae9gr6m" "log,deny,msg:'Access Denied'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I was missing, was Processing phase, in which this rule must be put to make it work. so the actual rule is here.

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI|ARGS|REQUEST_BODY "km0ae9gr6m" "phase:4,log,deny,msg:'Access Denied'"
```

By this rule, you can easily block any type of response,that you do not want any user to see. Modsecurity will detect it on its way out to server and will block it.

Comment: in phase 4 you won't block anything... it already hit your server and you're responding to request...

Answer (score 8):

Which ModSecurity version are you using? `ARGS` variable only includes `QUERY_STRING` + `POST_PAYLOAD` in version 1.X. If you're running version 2.X, with your above rule, testing with a request as below:

```
http://domain.com/a?b=km0ae9gr6m
```

you'll see something like this in the `audit_log`:

`[modsecurity] [client x.x.x.x] [domain domain.com] [302] [/20120813/20120813-1226/20120813-122624-70QXqH8AAAEA
AEucDbkAAAAA]  [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf"] [line "305"] [msg "Access Denied"] Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "km0ae9gr6m" at ARGS:b.`

In ModSecurity 2.x, `ARGS` expands to individual variables. So, try this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI|ARGS|REQUEST_BODY "km0ae9gr6m" "log,deny,msg:'Access Denied'"
```

Comment: i am using modsecurity 2.6. And i have created an html page having this string in it. i have hosted that page on apache and with your rule above, it still opens the page and does not detects this string.

Comment: I have tried with RESPONSE_BODY match as well, but still not working. i have pasted this string in an html page, tried to open it remotely and it opened without any issues.

Comment: Your original question is not clear. If you want to filter output, as you posted belows, do it in [`phase:4`](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.5.7/html-multipage/processing-phases.html).

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct, use phase:1. You can also use the "@contains" partial string match operator to stop a request that has the unwanted string as part of a longer string. For example, I don't have word press, so when I get requests for wp-login, wp-admin, etc., I can block them all with one rule:
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains wp-" "id:101,phase:1,deny,status:409,msg:'Denied'"

On a side note, the message from msg: seems to only appear in the logs, the message the user sees I have added in the apache config
ErrorDocument 409 "ACCESS STRICTLY FORBIDDEN"

Comment: Which answer says to use `phase:1`? And why do you send 409 Conflict?